# VSCode change setting ctrl + s

Tags: visual-studio-code

Please forgive my English.
I use Visual studio code.
I inserted Ctrl + s, cursor was move finish line.
I want cursor in place before.
What I things to do?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+S is for saving changes in files. It's not about cursor's behavior.
Try call to mind what did you changed in settings and fix it. 
If you can't remember - just delete the editor. And download it again.